# Share Salesforce dashboard as pdf

Tags: sharing, dashboard, scheduled-job

I have developed a dashboard with multiple reports with and without charts. The dashboard is working fine and the customer is happy. However, customer wants to schedule the dashboard refresh and share the results to certain people via email.

I have done some research and it looks like sharing the dashboard results as a pdf is not yet supported by Salesforce.

Can someone help and let me know if there is a way to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can share the dashboard result via email into other salesforce users by `Subscribe dashboard` function. It's share the dashboard result into the users based on the subscription time.

You can refer this [docx](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dashboards_subscribe_lex.htm&type=5) to know how to subscribe the dashboard.

Thanks.